# Python - open new shell and run command

Tags: python, shell, terminal, command

At the moment I am running a bash command from within Python using the following method:

```
os.system(cmd)
```

However I need to run the command in a new shell/terminal. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: By "new terminal" do you mean you want your window manager to create a new terminal window in which the command runs?

Answer (score 8):

I am using the following method (this will also redirect stderr to stdout):

```
import subprocess    
cmd_line = "echo Hello!"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd_line, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
out = p.communicate()[0]
print out
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.system()` is deprecated in favour of :

```
import subprocess
print subprocess.check_output("command", shell=True)
```

Comment: does this actually make a new separete process or just a subshell?  bcs subshells can have conflicts with file handes. ie using os.system() is bad since thats a subshell

Answer (score 1):

Windows "WshShell", Google it, is the answer. My complete steps:

Install

```
1. pip install pywin32-221-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
2. python.exe pywin32_postinstall.py -install  (DOS command line)
```

Run

```
3. import win32com.client
4. WshShell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
5. WshShell.run("cmd")
```

WshShell.run() is what you need, there are many different ways to run. hidden window, new window, full screen, minimized, ... etc.